SSLHandshakeException in ClientHello handshake message
I have a Java client that connects to the remote system, to get the token. It's failing with the SSLHandshakeException.
The Java client code:
public class OauthValidation {

    
    private static final String TOKEN_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.example.com.country_code/auth/1.0/token";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "ACTUAL_CLIENT_ID";
    
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "ACTUAL_SECRET";
    private static final String  SCOPE = "ACTUAL_SCOPE";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OAuthSystemException, OAuthProblemException {
        
    
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        System.out.println("props -" + System.getProperty("https.protocols"));
        OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
        OAuthClientRequest request =
                            OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(TOKEN_REQUEST_URL)
                            .setGrantType(GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                            .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                            .setScope(SCOPE)
                            .buildBodyMessage();
                    
        
                String token = client.accessToken(request, 
                               OAuth.HttpMethod.POST, 
                               OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class).getAccessToken();
                    System.out.println(token);
    }

}


After enabled the -Djavax.net.debug=all its found that it is failing in the ClientHello handshake
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2024-09-12 11:19:58.389 CDT|null:-1|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "84424812FF89D5D32BE1E394B29CBB1CC15447E89619A34481F87F6AC488F16F",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA(0xC008), SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA(0x0013), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA(0xC003), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=api.example.com.country_code
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|10|main|2024-09-12 11:19:58.395 CDT|null:-1|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.setRequestBody(URLConnectionClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:91)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at OauthValidation.main(OauthValidation.java:41)
  Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2024-09-12 11:19:58.395 CDT|null:-1|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2024-09-12 11:19:58.396 CDT|null:-1|close the SSL connection (passive)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at OauthValidation.main(OauthValidation.java:41)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.setRequestBody(URLConnectionClient.java:124)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:91)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more

Further ran the  openssl s_client -connect api.example.com.country_code:443 -prexit -showcerts and it resulted in the below output.
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 319 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 319 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---


Also tried the answers from this Stackoverflow question, but it did not work as well - Set TLS Version
Validated the cacerts file and it has the valid certificates.
Your suggestion is welcome. Need inputs from the community members to debug and fix this issue. Thank you !!
Source - On-prem server
Destination - Public cloud server

In this case, the flow/control  from source to destination is :
source -> Web Application Firewall -> Netskope -> Cloudflare -> destination.
In this case, the Netskope policy is blocking the traffic to the destination.  Updating the policy is fixed the issue.


javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
...
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 319 bytes


The connection was closed directly after the ClientHello by the peer without further information, i.e. simply closed without any TLS alert. This is before the server has send any certificates, so this error is definitely not related to certificate validation.
Without access to the server side of the connection one can only speculate what the reason might be.
But this kind of error pattern is common with DPI (deep packet inspection) firewalls on the host or in the network filtering access: they allow the initial TCP handshake but then reset the connection once they determined the target domain based on server_name in the ClientHello.
But this is still only speculation. If you have access to the server check if there are any errors in the server logs regarding this connection. If not make sure that the ClientHello even arrives at the server (i.e. not blocked by a firewall in the middle) and that the connection close is even initiated by the server (and not by a firewall in the middle). If you don't have access to the server try switching off all firewalls  on your system and make sure that there are no firewalls interferring in the network (i.e. try different network).

First, make sure you use the -servername argument in your OpenSSL command:  openssl s_client -connect api.example.com.country_code:443 -servername api.example.com.country_code -prexit -showcerts.  That will set the Server Name Indication (SNI) field, and the server may require that to properly route your connection attempt.
Then in addition to Steffen Ulrich's answer, if your Java client doesn't share supported TLS version(s) and cipher suite(s) with the server, the server could just drop the connection without a proper error reported.  It's not nice, but I've seen it, although IMO it's not likely and another network problem is more likely.
For example, I get the exact same result using openssl -connect www.mybank.com:443 -servername www.mybank.com -no_tls1_2.  But openssl -connect www.mybank.com:443 -servername www.mybank.com successfully connects.  I don't even get the courtesy of a TLS protocol version alert. 
What version(s) of OpenSSL and Java are you using?  If they're older, you clients might not have a common set of TLS version(s) and cipher suite(s) with the server, although it appears fairly recent from what you've posted.

s_client defaults -servername and thus you no longer need to specify it since 1.1.1 in 2018, and OP must be using such a version since the line in the summary for "Early data" only exists in 1.1.1 up. The Java log format shows it must be 11 up or 8u261 up, and is capable of TLS1.3 but not offering it due to the https.protocols setting. However that openssl is offering 1.3 (with basically all known suites except the pre-1.3 'aNULL' and 'eNULL' ones, and all known sigalgs) and the server -- or something -- mislikes that just as much.
